# Gitlab CI: create multiple builds from single commit

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My current gitlab configuration is very simple as below

```
stages:
 - build

before_script:
  - some commands here

build-after-commit:
 stage: build
 script:
  - some command here
 artifacts:
  expire_in: 1 day
  when: on_success
  name: name here
  paths:
    - build/*.zip
```

I want to run build-after-commit part twice with different settings. I am expecting something like this

```
stages:
 - build

before_script:
  - some commands here

build-after-commit:
 stage: build
 script:
  - some command here
 artifacts:
  expire_in: 1 day
  when: on_success
  name: name1 here
  paths:
    - build/*.zip

 # run it again with different settings
 stage: build
 script:
  - Different script here
 artifacts:
  expire_in: 1 day
  when: on_success
  name: name2 here
  paths:
    - build/*.zip
```

So basically, in the second run the script will be different and the name of the output file will be different. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward approach would be to just have another job in the build stage.

E.g.

```
stages:
 - build

before_script:
  - some commands here


build-after-commit:
    stage: build
    script:
    - some command here
    artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
    when: on_success
    name: name1 here
    paths:
    - build/*.zip

build-after-commit2:
    stage: build
    script:
    - Different script here
    artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
    when: on_success
    name: name2 here
    paths:
        - build/*.zip
```

If you define `build-after-commit2` in the same stage (`build`) it will even be run in parallel to `build-after-commit`. 
In this case, I don't think having two jobs is bad design, as they are actually quite different from each other i.e. different script and different artifact name.